# Need to know which sprite was clicked

Tags: actionscript-3

This is my level selector for a game. You can choose level 1-8, I need to know which one was clicked. e.target doesn't give me much besides the name of the object. I need to know either the place in the array or the name of the picture so I know which level to load up.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class LevelSelector extends Sprite 
    {
        private var posX:int = 50;
        private var posY:int = 50;

        [Embed(source="../lib/one.png")]
        private var lvl1Class:Class;
        private var lvl1:Bitmap = new lvl1Class();

        [Embed(source="../lib/two.png")]
        private var lvl2Class:Class;
        private var lvl2:Bitmap = new lvl2Class();

        [Embed(source="../lib/three.png")]
        private var lvl3Class:Class;
        private var lvl3:Bitmap = new lvl3Class();

        [Embed(source="../lib/four.png")]
        private var lvl4Class:Class;
        private var lvl4:Bitmap = new lvl4Class();

        [Embed(source="../lib/five.png")]
        private var lvl5Class:Class;
        private var lvl5:Bitmap = new lvl5Class();

        [Embed(source="../lib/six.png")]
        private var lvl6Class:Class;
        private var lvl6:Bitmap = new lvl6Class();

        [Embed(source="../lib/seven.png")]
        private var lvl7Class:Class;
        private var lvl7:Bitmap = new lvl7Class();

        [Embed(source="../lib/eight.png")]
        private var lvl8Class:Class;
        private var lvl8:Bitmap = new lvl8Class();

        private var myArrayBitmaps:Array = new Array;
        private var myArraySprites:Array = new Array;

        private var yCounter:int = 1;

        public function LevelSelector():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }
        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point

            myArrayBitmaps.push(false, lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, lvl4, lvl5, lvl6, lvl7, lvl8);

            for (var i:int = 1; i < 9; i++) 
            {
                myArrayBitmaps[i].x = posX;
                myArrayBitmaps[i].y = posY;
                myArrayBitmaps[i].height = 50;
                myArrayBitmaps[i].width = 100;
                //myArrayBitmaps[i].name = "lvl_" + i + "";

                myArraySprites[i] = new Sprite();
                myArraySprites[i].addChild(myArrayBitmaps[i]);
                myArraySprites[i].x = posX;
                myArraySprites[i].y = posY;
                //myArraySprites[i].name = "lvl_" + i + "";

                stage.addChild(myArraySprites[i]);

                myArraySprites[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void {
                    removeThis(e, this);
                });

                posX += 100;
                yCounter += 1;
                if (yCounter == 5) {
                    posY += 100;
                    posX -= 400;
                }
            }
        }
        private function removeThis(e:MouseEvent, temp):void
        {
            //Need to know the number which was passed, 1-8
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
//...
private function init(e:Event = null):void 
{
    //...
    for (var i:int = 1; i < 9; i++) 
    {
        //...
        myArraySprites[i] = new Sprite();
        myArraySprites[i].addChild(myArrayBitmaps[i]);
        //...
        stage.addChild(myArraySprites[i]);

        myArraySprites[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removeThis);


        }
    }
}
private function removeThis(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var clickTarget:int = myArraySprites.indexOf(e.currentTarget);
    trace("Clicked sprite (id): " + clickTarget);
}
```

Comment: This is 2014, May 25th, I just ran into the same problem, and i saw this set of code above, it helped me resolved my problem as well!! Thanks!!!